# How do I add multiple new rows from a list of lists in gspread python?

Tags: python, gspread

I have a list of lists that I would like to append to the end of the row in Google Sheets

```
# assume I added a worksheet variable that contains the worksheet
example_list = [['33 years old', 'John Apple', '1012', 'friend'], ['18 years old', 'George Eperon', '1013', 'unknown'], ['21 years old', 'Jesper Lokosir', '1014', 'friend']]

worksheet.append_rows(example_list)
```

**Expected result:**

[image: Here is what I mean by appending the row in this way]

How would I append a list such as this at the bottom of the sheet?

I happen to find the function **append_rows** in the gspread docs, but I get this error when adding a list such as the one above

*gspread.exceptions.APIError: 'code': 400, 'message': 'Invalid value at 'data.values[0]' (type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.ListValue)*

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I fixed the problem. It seems that I used a 1d array in my original code instead of a 2d one such as the one I did here I apologize.